# java.math.BigInteger cannot be cast to java.math.BigDecimal

Tags: java, sql, oracle, postgresql, math

We are migrating from Oracle to PostgreSQL. Some queries that were specific to Oracle had to be changed to Postgres equivalents. Following is one such commit:

Initially,

```
Query query = getEntityManager().createNativeQuery("SELECT PC_SITE_GROUP_ID_SEQ.NEXTVAL from DUAL");
BigDecimal result = (BigDecimal) query.getSingleResult();
```

was changed to,

```
Query query = getEntityManager().createNativeQuery("SELECT NEXTVAL('pc_site_group_id_seq')");
BigDecimal result = (BigDecimal) query.getSingleResult();
```

On running, after the change, it threw error,

> java.math.BigInteger cannot be cast to java.math.BigDecimal

My question is why it was working before?
Just a reminder, the first change was run on Oracle database while the second one on Postgres database. Please help.

Comment: "My question is why it was working before" - just a guess but it might be the oracle jdbc driver that mapped the value to a `BigDecimal`. What does that "DUAL" mean here? How did you define your sequence? Could it be a floating/fixed point number in the Oracle case?

Comment: @Thomas it's the oracle "syntax requires a table, but there's no need for a table, so use DUAL as a pretend table" way.

Comment: @Kayaman My version is 11.2.0.3.0.

Comment: @Life_Hacker It might be an issue with the Oracle DB Driver you have used, Can you try it with a latest DB driver.

Comment: I can't use Oracle. As said earlier we are migrating from it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Oracle has no "integer" data type in the database so everything is mapped to BigDecimal by the driver.

In Postgres there is a clear distinction between an integer (or bigint) and a decimal, so the driver returns a BigInteger for `bigint` values.

And a sequence always emits `bigint` values, so the driver returns a `BigInteger` for them.

Comment: Can you take a look at this url, https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B12037_01/server.101/b10759/statements_6014.htm It is mentioned that `nextVal` will return an `integer`

Comment: @Jobin: Oracle has no native `integer` data type. Everything is a `number` which could contain decimals. And regardless on what the Oracle _server_ sends, the driver converts this to a BigDecimal. Plus the default max value for a sequence would fit into a BigInteger - so the driver **has** to use a `BigDecimal`

Comment: BigDecimal (BigDecimal, without precision (large integer Postgres or double)) in Oracle and in Postgres db it has the equivalent column using an integer datatype.

Comment: So it's just a case of Oracle being Oracle.

Comment: @Kayaman: no, really.  `BigDecimal` is the only choice the driver has, because the potential values of a sequence (actually a `number` in general) do not fit into a `BigInteger`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name your comment contradicts your answer. If Postgres driver returns BigDecimal then why it is throwing an error. Please explain if I misunderstood it.

Comment: Well yes, but wouldn't you consider Oracle's approach a bit curious from the perspective of someone not used to Oracle. That's what I meant by Oracle being Oracle. You wouldn't encounter these kinds of oddities between let's say MySQL, Postgres and Sql Server.

Comment: @Life_Hacker: thanks, corrected (that was just a typo)